# RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver android

Tags: android

I'm new in the android. I defined the BroadcastReceiver in the same activity and Even I entered the entry in the AndroidManifest.xml but I'm getting exception.

```
public class CheckTicketReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        message = intent.getAction();

        if(message != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(message.equals("100")) {
                intent = new Intent(); 
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.sec.android.wallet", "com.sec.android.wallet.ui.activity.ticket.ExternalTicketDetailViewActivity")); 
                // Ticket ID (mandatory) 
                intent.putExtra("TICKET_ID", ticketId); 
                // Bounce ID (optional), set as the current system timestamp in milliseconds 
                intent.putExtra("BOUNCE_ID", ""+System.currentTimeMillis()); 
                // RESULT_ACTION (mandatory) 
                intent.putExtra("RESULT_ACTION", "com.sample.partners.action.VIEW_TICKET_RESULT"); 
                startActivity(intent); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".BrandDetailActivity$CheckTicketReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.sec.android.wallet.action.CHECK_TICKET" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Stacktrace

```
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.passbeemedia.BrandDetailActivity$CheckTicketReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.passbeemedia.BrandDetailActivity$CheckTicketReceiver
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1777)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.passbeemedia.BrandDetailActivity$CheckTicketReceiver
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1768)
10-23 00:54:37.148: E/AndroidRuntime(19923):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Here is your answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328963/instantiationexception-when-using-newinstance-on-broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the class static and it solved my issue.

Thanks Anirudh